# Leaflet tile lines visible

Tags: firefox, maps, rendering, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and have custom tiles. I notice that at certain zoom levels, both in the map itself and zoom levels for the browser, I see the outline of where the tile borders are. I feel there's a rendering issue with firefox but not sure, just wondering if others have run into this issue and if people have gotten around this. Leaflet API doesn't mention leaflet limitations....

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and it turned out that the page was scaled up ever so slightly in Firefox (not sure how it got that way).  Try resetting the zoom on the page (CMD + 0 on Mac).

Comment: just experienced this same issue and resetting the zoom fixed the problem. thanks!

Comment: ‍♀️ oh boy... more sleep tomorrow....